# How to do taxonomy based css styling using drupal template.php?

Tags: css, drupal, taxonomy

I'm looking forward to implement taxonomy terms based css styling; especially for the body tag which i want to add the current terms.

For now, here's what i have so far :

```
function _phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars = array()) {
    global $node;
    switch ($hook) {
        case 'page':            die ('test');
            $vars['body_class'] = '';
            if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
                $vars['body_class'] = 'theme'.arg(2);
            }
            if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
                $node = node_load(arg(1));
                if (is_array($node->taxonomy)) {
                    foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
                        $vars['body_class'] .= 'theme'.$term->tid;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
                $vars['body_class'] .= ' front';
            }
            break;
    }
    return $vars; 
}
```

I think the code is OK, but it never get called (see my 'die' function); using simple phptemplate engine and minimal drupal6 install.

What obviousity am I missing here ?

Comment: function  _phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars) { die ('here'); } never gets executed too.

Comment: So, now I know that's not the problem! But I had to ask :-)

Comment: Is the script ever executed? if you place `die('here');` outside any function will it die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Override or insert PHPTemplate variables into the templates.
 */
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  //
}

/**
 * Override or insert PHPTemplate variables into the templates.
 */
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, years ago we wrote this up http://openconcept.ca/blog/jmlane/taxonomy_specific_css

It would need to be updated I expect for Drupal 6 or 7 but the principals still apply.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 a more elegant solution might be to use the [Context module](https://drupal.org/project/context). See the following posting for detailed information and instructions.

- [Add a body class based on a node's vocabulary term](https://drupal.org/node/1257822)

The Context modules allows for creating arbitrary contexts for specific Drupal pages, e.g. based on taxonomy terms. These contexts can trigger certain reactions, e.g. add a CSS class with the chosen taxonomy term.

Comment: Single link answers are not the best. Please describe in a few words what is found at the end of the URL